# Template tag for going from model1 to model2 that has foreign key to model1

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Is there a template tag or a way that I can go from my main model to a specific model that has a foreign key to my main model?

**models.py**

```
class BillingAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserCart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)

class HomeAddress(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserCart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True)

class UserCart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

I want to get the 'address1' field from the BillingAddress that is related to a usercart. I don't think that I can use {{usercart.address1}} as both HomeAddress and BillingAddress have a field called address1 and are related to the usercart.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont worry, you can get it normally. Because `BillingAddress` and `HomeAddress` FK to `UserCart`.This mean from `UserCart`, you have 2 set different is  `usercart.billingaddress_set` and `usercart.homeaddress_set`. This is 2 list of `BillingAddress` and `HomeAddress` related with `UserCart`.

If you want get one `address1` field. You must know what `set` you want get it. Like example : `usercart.billingaddress_set.first().address1` will give you first record which `BillingAddress` related with `UserCart`.

If you still worry, you can change name of `billingaddress_set` or `homeaddress_set` by `related_name` to anything name you want. Read [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for more information

Comment: You should use `first` if you are using this in a template - `first()` won't work as parentheses aren't used in template ORM syntax.